# To show Ajax call value on same controller while using front controller

Tags: php, ajax, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I wanted to send ajax data to controller page and display ajax data on template file in prestashop 1.6 .

I am using this method but not able to get any results -

**tpl file :**

`<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="test" onclick = "testing()" value="test" />`

```
function testing() {
        url = '{$link->getModuleLink("hotelapi", "filter")|escape:"html"}';
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type : 'GET',
            cache : false,
            data : {
                ajax: 1,
                action: 'fetchTPL',
            },
            success: function(html){
                alert("SUCCESS:");
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("ERROR:");
            }
        });

    }
```

Front Controller file - File name is - filter.php

```
<?php 
/*require (dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../../config/config.inc.php');
require (dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../../init.php');*/

class hotelapiFilterModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{
    public function displayAjaxFetchTPL()
    {
        echo 'hello'; 
        //after processing all data just assign it to smarty of content
        /*$this->context->smarty->assign(array(
            'youContentData' => $_POST['room'])
        );

        // to fetch a tpl file use fetch method and use die function to return the response to ajax
        die($this->context->smarty->fetch('a1.tpl'));*/

    }

}
```

My ajax url is executing successfully but I am not able to print anything written inside displayAjaxFetchTPL action.

Please anyone help me with this problem.

Thanks and regards,
Ridhi Bhutani

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the "onclick" event on your button, why not use a JQuery event lsitener?

Your HTML would be something like this:

`<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="test" value="test" />`

And your JS like this:

```
$("#test").on("click", function () {
    url = '{$link->getModuleLink("hotelapi", "filter")|escape:"html"}';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        data: {
            ajax: 1,
            action: 'fetchTPL',
        },
        success: function (html) {
            alert("SUCCESS:"+html);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("ERROR:");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi,
By using jquery event listener also I am not able to echo "hello" written in my filter.php controller.

Please help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: Did you console.log(html); in success function?

Comment: @Sachin,
Yes, this returned nothing. In console nothing is showing. But it is showing success alert.

Comment: Would you mind open your module url directly. I mean 
check this value and open direct in browser.
url = '{$link->getModuleLink("hotelapi", "filter")|escape:"html"}';

Comment: @Sachin,
Yes I have executed this url directly in browser also, by copying the link from INSPECT--->NETWORK and then executed the link. 
But it is showing nothing. I can only see white screen.

Comment: Mmmm just edited my answer to show the response in the alert.

Answer (score 0):

php:

```
public function displayAjaxFetchTPL()
{
    $data = ['mYtxt' => 'hello'];
    die(Tools::jsonEncode($data)); 
}
```

jquery:

```
success: function (html) {
        alert(html.mYtxt);
    },
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.